# Query Update does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working with MySQLi and I wanted now I made a form to edit some entries in the database and of course I want to update the data in the database. But for some reason nothing happen. No error either.. I allready used var_dump to see if the php script is getting the data from the form, works fine. 
Maybe someone can find any mistakes at the update code.

```
$con->query("UPDATE anime SET 
 epcount = '".$eps."',
 original_title = '".$otitle."',
 japan_title = '".$jtitle."',
 english_title = '".$etitle."',
 genres = '".$genres."',
 studio = '".$studio."',
 season = '".$season."',
 year = '".$year."',
 state = '".$status."',
 type = '".$type."',
 manifestations = '".$manif."',
 trailer = '".$trailer."',
 description = '".$des."' WHERE id = '$animeId");
```

Comment: You should accept an answer, or else this question is listed as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the last line

```
$con->query("UPDATE anime SET 
 epcount = '".$eps."',
 original_title = '".$otitle."',
 japan_title = '".$jtitle."',
 english_title = '".$etitle."',
 genres = '".$genres."',
 studio = '".$studio."',
 season = '".$season."',
 year = '".$year."',
 state = '".$status."',
 type = '".$type."',
 manifestations = '".$manif."',
 trailer = '".$trailer."',
 description = '".$des."' WHERE id = '".$animeId."'");
```

Also making the query in this style is a bad practice

Comment: Huh? Why? How would you do it?

Comment: @user3084925 Learn about SQL injection. You'll figure it out yourself.

Comment: @user3084925 - if you're using mysqli, you can use bound parameters and prepared statements. They help you make your code more secure; at the moment, what would happen if there's an apostrophe in the title of your film?

Comment: @user3084925 as codeAngry told you it's some security issues in this way, also if you found my answer useful please try to accept it :)

Comment: I'm using htmlspecialchars when getting the variables at the start of the script. Is that what you mean?